# nfs client in vmware: access denied by server?

Tags: nfs

I have 2 machines with identically configured /etc/fstab's and identical versions of Ubuntu LTS. Fstab

```
otherhost:/otherdir /mnt/otherdir nfs defaults 0 0
```

When mounting an nfs client:

```
mount /mnt/otherdir
```

one machine worked and the other failed with a "access denied by server" error.

Answer (score 2):

This is because sometimes NFSv4 does a problem with Ubuntu. I suggest you to use NFSv3 in a shared environment like that

Please edit the `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server`

Edit the line as

```
RPCNFSDARGS="--no-nfs-version 4"
```

Add the following line

```
MOUNTD_NFS_V3="yes"
```

Then restart it

```
restart nfs-kernel-server
```

Test it, you will see no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked the cause to be that one was running in a VM that was configured to share its network interface with its host computer, the other was configured in bridge mode.

Only bridged mode works for nfs (as far as I can tell). After running mount -vv I found that the nfs-client sending its IP address to the nfs-server. In non-bridged mode, this IP address doesn't exist on the network (its a virtual IP address invented by the VM software). In this case the connection fails. Solution: switch the interface to bridge-mode in the VM software.

Comment: In Virtualbox I wanted to mount a folder on the host machine from the vm (using nat), and had to add 127.0.0.1 to my /etc/exports